# When I try to write something in Django urls.py file, it doesn't show this in the browser

Tags: python, django

```
#code in urls.py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.index, name= 'index'),
    path('about/', views.about, name ='about'),
]
#code in views.py

from django.http import HttpResponse

def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello")

def about(request):
    return HttpResponse("about harry")
```

## Body

I am doing this while watching a tutorial, and the same thing is working for him. Moreover, if mistakenly I write the wrong code and run, cmd shows the errors and on reloading the browser the server doesn't work more. Then I need to restart CMD and again run manage.py. Please tell me the reason and also the solution, Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that you saved applied changes to file? Maybe in tutorial he has autosave.

Comment: Now the files have been saved, but changes on browser are not made. Earlier this was not the case.

Comment: What command are you using to run your application?

Comment: "python manage.py runserver"

Answer (score -1):

What errors do you get? 
Besides there're 2 urls' files: url routes for pages are inside urls.py in the same folder where views.py are. In another urls.py (the one which is in the same folder with manage.py) you may need to write following, assuming that 'polls' is the name of you application:

```
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
    path('polls/', include('polls.urls')),
]
```

According to Django docs: include() function allows referencing other URLconfs. Whenever Django encounters include(), it chops off whatever part of the URL matched up to that point and sends the remaining string to the included URLconf for further processing.
You should always use include() when you include other URL patterns. admin.site.urls is the only exception to this.

If you still get the error: check that you’re going to http://localhost:8000/polls/ and not http://localhost:8000/

Comment: It's working on "http://127.0.0.1:8000/". And I have do that you told me to do for about page. And about page is not loading.

Comment: So what are the errors that you get? Have you included the name of your app in the route as written above?

Comment: +Ogla Yes I have done this.. This error is shown on cmd, "You have 15 unapplied migrations, your project may not work properly untill you apply migrations for app (s), admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions" And many other errors, but I think its the major one. I wanted to show you all but I couldn't copy them from cmd.

Comment: If it's about db, then run: python manage.py makemigrations and then python manage.py migrate. Though I don't see any models here.

Comment: after running "python manage.py makemigrations", cmd replied: "no changes detected"

Comment: +Ogla thank you very much, now my code is running successfully. There was some problem in the project. I have deleted that project and created another one and now its working fine. Thanks for you concern.